# Testing RGB Values using glob pattern

Tags: bash

I would like to watch an rgb pattern and confirm values are within `0` to `255` in a bash function.  What can I do.

Here is the glob pattern I constructed.

```
pglob="+([[:digit:]]);+([[:digit:]]);+([[:digit:]])"
```

The foreground RGB colour sequence is stored in `kf`, whereas the background
RGB colour sequence is stored in `kb`.

The colour representation for foreground and background colour are then `frps`
and `brps` respectively.

```
kf="135;28;2"

kb="0;0;0"

if [[ "$kf" == $pglob ]]; then
   ## test rgb values here on string KF 
   frps="\e[38;2;${kf}m"
fi

if [[ "$kb" == $pglob ]]; then
   ## test rgb values here on string KF 
   brps="\e[38;2;${kf}m"
fi
```

Comment: It is unclear what your issue is. The code, as given, sets the `frps` variable. Is the issue that the values may be larger than 255? What creates the `kf` string? Did you attempt a stricter pattern than one that matches three `;`-separated strings of digits?

Comment: I want to ensure that the numeric values are valid.  Have been thinking of doing a general pattern first, then extract the individual values  `${ir};${ig};${ib}`.

Comment: The `kf` and `kb` strings are passed by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest six numerical comparisons with `bash`:

```
kf="0;128;255";

# split $kf with ";" to variables $r, $g and $b
IFS=";" read -r r g b <<< "$kf";
if [[ $r -ge 0 && $r -le 255 && $g -ge 0 && $g -le 255 && $b -ge 0 && $b -le 255 ]]; then
  echo "$r $g $b okay";
fi
```

> **-ge**: greater-than-or-equal

> **-le**: less-than-or-equal

Comment: Would I have to reset `IFS` after it is changed ?

Comment: No, the variable IFS is set only in the context of `read` because of the missing comma before `read`.

Comment: I fixed two typos in my code.

Comment: Can I split `kf` to an array this way `agr=(${kf//;/ })` ?

Comment: Yes, see `declare -p agr`.